# Writing bytes into an executable file in c

Tags: c, file, byte, fwrite

I'm actually trying to encrypt some files using a c program.
So what i did is reading the file, storing the bytes in a variable, spliting the variable into to (to encrypt it using Blowfish), joining the two variables again into one and writing it to a file, but when debugging the program I always get a Segmentation Fault in this part wich is the last one :

```
newFile = fopen(newPath,"ab+");
fwrite(&srvBuf,1,BUFF_SIZE,newFile);
fclose(newFile);
printf("Finished");

/* Where srvBuf is my encrypted bytes, BUFF_SIZE is the size of the file,
   newPath is the new file path */
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: replace `fwrite(&srvBuf,1,BUFF_SIZE,newFile);` by `fwrite(srvBuf,1,BUFF_SIZE,newFile);`. Anyway show the declaration of `srvBuf`. Also check if `newFile` is not NULL after `fopen`.

Comment: This question is badly asked. There is not enough code to understand the problem. You should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in help center and particurlarly the part on MVCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should check that

   newFile != NULL

Its possible for fopen to fail for many many reasons ( directory does not exist, user lacks permissions etc. )

2. You don't show the code for how srvBuf is written, or how big it is. The error can easily be there. Are you sure that srvBuf is BUFF_SIZE bytes long?